# How to keep reference to captured smart pointer in lambda function?

Tags: c++, c++11, atl

Suppose the following code:

```
void SomeClass::SomeMethod()
{
    CComPtr<ISomeService> service = GetService();

    ExecuteInNewThread([&]()
    {
        service->AnotherMethod();
    });
}
```

The function ExecuteInNewThread executes function object in new thread thus the lambda function may be executed after the service pointer will be released.
What would be the best way to prevent this? Doing AddRef() in SomeMethod and Release() at the end of the lambda looks ugly.

Comment: Why not capture the smart pointer by value? (I have no idea what CCompPtr is/does.)

Comment: Capturing local variables by reference for function executed in new thread is weird... and wrong.

Comment: @Mat, thank you. I just forget that there is an option to capture variables by value in lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture the variable by value and let the copy constructor and destructor worry about ownership semantics- that's what smart pointers are for. The existing code is most assuredly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If a closure object containing references to local variables is invoked after the innermost block scope of its creation, the behaviour is undefined.

I would have thought that executing a closure object on a different thread would also be undefined.